# 2d thrust::device_vector to kernel

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, thrust

I have a data type defined as `typedef InitialState float[12]`. I have a vector containing several initial states defined by `std::vector<InitialState> h_initials`.

I made it a thrust device vector : `thrust::device_vector<InitialState> d_initials = h_initials;`

I would like to use this data is a user-defined kernel. However, I'm having problems casting it to a raw pointer. I've tried

`float *p_initials = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_initials[0]);`

but `thrust` complains `function returning array is not allowed`.

Is there a way I can cast the device vector to a pointer that the kernel can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InitialState (float[12]) != float

```
InitialState *p_initials = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_initials.data());
float* p_floats = (float*)p_initials;
```

However, this is generally wrong to start with, because of the weird behavior below

```
typedef int int4[4];
void test(int4 a)
{
   std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int4 f;
  std::cout << sizeof(f) << std::endl;//returns 16 (4*sizeof(int))
  test(f);//returns 8 (size of pointer, passes by reference)
}
```

Whats better is this:

```
struct InitialState{float value[12];}
std::vector<InitialState> h_initials;
thrust::device_vector<InitialState> d_initials = h_initials;
InitialState *p_initials = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_initials.data());
float* p_floats = (float*)p_initials;
```

And in cuda, you can use either InitialState* or float* as the argument (though SOA works better than AOS)

Comment: This is an excellent solution. Thank you for your help. I would accept this answer twice if I could.